Flight search engine that can show the cheapest flight excluding self transfer and third-party deals
Hi,
I'm trying to find the cheapest ticket betweentwo cities in the last week of October. I tried using Kayak, Skyscanner, and Google Flights. However, the "cheapest" flights listed by these sites are always the self-transfer type tickets or tickets where third-party websites combine two tickets from two different airlines or extremely long flights with long travel times.
Is there any website that lists the cheapest flights in a given time interval that satisfies some conditions?
For example, if I want to find the cheapest flight from Stockholm to Dubai with the following conditions

Route: Stockholm to Dubai
Date range: 20/October/2024 to 30/October/2024
Flight duration: less than 20 hours
Luggage: one cabin bag + one checked in bag


On Google Flights, you can exclude self-transfers by clicking on "All Filters" then at the very bottom "Hide separate tickets". It won't take into account checked bags though. Pegasus seems to be consistently the cheapest, and is cheapest on 30 October.

Thanks, it does. But it still shows separate tickets that are combined by third-party websites. Is it possible to get rid of that too? Also can google flights show a date range? Kiwi can do this both, but they don't show many flights such as AirFrance.

When you select that option it still shows you separate tickets combined by third-party websites? It doesn't for me, and that's the whole point of that filter. Or we have a misunderstand on what you want to filter.

Maybe I'm wrong, for example, look at this flight "https://www.google.com/travel/flights/s/vaERD75HqeQHhQNw7" this is Lufthansa+Oman air, but this is not available in  Oman air website. I guess this is a third-party combination.
To see this search ARN-COK  on 30/October/2024

I can still see flights like these in google flights even when I turn off the option you suggested

I don't think they're separate tickets, just different airlines on a single ticket. For some reason airlines don't always show those on their websites, but they can be ticketed (as Google says, you need to call them).

Thanks! But in this case, booking through SuperSaver is 4628 SEK, but when I book through direct call it is almost 10 times 37,192 SEK.

Are you perhaps overestimating the difficulty of excluding self-transfers yourself? Just use your favourite search engine, order the available flights by price, and go down them until you find one that isn't a self-transfer.

The most flexible search engine is https://matrix.itasoftware.com/search . I don't think they offer self-connections and you can specify minimum and maximum connections times,  max flight duration etc. exclude certain airlines, ask for specific routing airports, a specific alliance, etc.
On the downside, they do not offer all low cost carriers (no Ryan Air, EZJet etc) and you can't specify baggage or seat type (e.g. lie flat).
For your constraints (ARN->DXB, < 20 hours, 10/20-10/30) the cheapest option is USD $241 on Sun Express with 10 hour layover in Izmir.
If you want to exclude Sun Express you can fly on Oct 29 with Finn Air and a very comfortable itinerary for USD $322. You will need to check baggage fees by hand.

Airlines really hate it when you do price comparisons. They used to advertise an $800 ticket for $50 (one way based on round trip purchase excl. taxes and fees) but many years ago they were forced by law to publish their actual prices. They have been looking for ways around this ever since and the current market distortion mechanism is ancillary fees (seats, baggage, carry on, food, check in, security, boarding, etc). Each airline has their own recipe on how they milk this: Bags can be reasonable or excruciatingly expensive, carry on may be included or not, you may get stuffed in a middle seat in the back of the plane unless you pay an extra $85 etc.
No search engine has caught up with this yet, and I doubt they ever will since the fees are intentionally based on complicated and confusing rules with too many factors to control.

Thanks, do you also know why some tickets that are available on third-party websites are not available on the airline's website?
for example, this flight Omanair+Lufthansa is a really good deal, but it is not available on either Omanair Lufthansa website:
https://www.google.com/travel/flights/s/vaERD75HqeQHhQNw7

Probably because Oman Air is One World and LH is Star Alliance, so they are not code share partners. Both have a strong incentive to sell you a itinerary  that stays within their alliance, and there are plenty of those available. I would be careful with this fare and double check whether this is really a single ticket. I don't even know how miles crediting would work here

@PhysicsStudent ITA Matrix says you should call Oman Air and give the full details of the fare construction. WY and LH are interline partners and even code-share partners on some flights, so despite their being in different alliances they can sell those tickets. They may prefer not to, but they should be able to. Not sure why it comes up with such a different price with LH, but it may be related to seat availability (sometimes partners have limited availability on the inventory of other airlines).

@PhysicsStudent interestingly enough, Oman Air do suggest a similar itinerary (with the same stops and airlines, but different flights/times... and price).

@Hilmar anecdotally, my aunt has taken a very similar routing twice in the past: LHE-MCT-FRA-YYZ-YWG, with Oman Air operating the first two legs and Lufthansa operating the next one out of FRA; in other words, this itinerary does definitely exist and can be booked as a single ticket. That being said, I believe she booked it through a travel agency, and those (including OTAs) are often the way to go for multi-airline itineraries which none of the airlines are selling directly.
